# What is the integral, $\int\frac{dx}{x + \sqrt{1-x²}}\ $?

Tags: definite-integrals

What is the integral,

$$\int\frac{dx}{x + \sqrt{1-x²}}\   ?$$

Comment: Is my edit correct?  If not please roll back.

Comment: Hmm, wonder if it helps to rationalize the denominator by multiplying and dividing by $x-\sqrt{1-x^2}$?

Comment: There is a classical change of variable suggested by the radical.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\int\frac{dx}{x + \sqrt{1-x^2}}\ 
$$
Take $x=\sin\theta$,
$$
\int\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta + \cos\theta} \, d\theta
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{2\cos\theta}{\sin\theta + \cos\theta} \, d\theta
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta} \, d\theta+\frac{1}{2} \int \frac{\cos\theta-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta+\sin\theta}\, d\theta
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2}\theta + \frac{1}{2}\ln|\cos\theta+\sin\theta|+C
$$
Substitute $\theta=\sin^{-1}x$ and you will get the answer.

Comment: It'd be better if constant C is added.